# jQuery - hide every element except the clicked element

Tags: jquery

I've got a jQuery fade in and out box called .flyout. When you click off of it I fade it out. I also want it to fade out if another one is clicked. I tried just hiding all .flyout classes, but that will cause the currently active .flyout to quickly fade in and out when you click on it. I've played around with jQuery not, parent, siblings etc and can't get it to work.

```
//hide flyout
$("body").on("click", function() {
    $(".flyout").fadeOut(150);
});
//show flyout
$(".rate").on("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".flyout", this).fadeIn(150);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hzuXq/). I did change your code a little bit. This does it per `.flyout` element so you have to click on each one individually. You'll see I added an `.active` class to the "active" flyout. Hope this helps!

```
$('.flyout').on("click", function() {
    if( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        $(this).fadeOut(150);
    } else {
        $(this).fadeOut(150);
        $(this).fadeIn(150);
    }
});
```